# jquery mobile back button does not display on first page

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

i have an app written with:

jquery 1.11.1
jquery mobile 1.4.5
cordova 4.3.0

my index.html looks like

```
<div data-role="page" id="id1">

  <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" style="height: auto">
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="id2">

  <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" style="height: auto">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

.
.
.

```
  <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" style="height: auto">
      <h1>Page X</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

i have onLoad() and onDeviceReady()

when my app starts i get the splash screen and then

```
<div data-role="page" id="id1">
```

displays.  but it has NO back button despite data-add-back-btn="true"

when

```
<div data-role="page" id="id2">
```

displays it DOES have a back button.

i don't understand what's wrong.  am i displaying the first page before before jquery mobile is ready enough to display the back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a back button on a first page.

What would be the point, where would it point to?

There's a workaround, create a third page, call it a dummy page. Make it empty and make it first in line. On pagecontainercreate (or pagecreate even if you're using older page events) just programmatically change page to #id1. This way you won't even notice dummy page and your now second page will have a back button.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4y7mav4a/

#### HTML

```
    <div data-role="page" id="hidden">

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="id1">

      <div data-role="header"  data-add-back-btn="true" style="height: auto">
          <h1>Page 1</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
          <a href="#id2">Go to page 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="id2">

      <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" style="height: auto">
          <h1>Page 2</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
      </div>
    </div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#hidden', function(){ 
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#id1");        
});
```

Comment: i was thinking clicking the Back button on the first page would exit the app.  i see now a Back button on the first page doesn't make much sense but how do you achieve the user being able to exit the app and make it shut down from the first page?  An Exit button?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-role="page" id="id1">

  <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" style="height: auto">
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
```

I had a similar problem and i solved it by adding this code

```
<a href="#page1" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>,
```

rigth after the:

```
<div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" style="height: auto">
```

Like this:

```
<div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" style="height: auto">
      <a href="#page1" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
<h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
```

With this you can have a back button wherever you want, the only problem is that you have to put a specific page, and you can erase the data-add-back-btn="true"

I hope this could help you or anyone else with this need